# Powershell - Streamreader -match limit returned results

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have the below code running in Powershell which searches for the string London, and works well thanks to some earlier assistance:

```
$sr = new-object System.io.streamreader(get-item C:\Temp\a.txt)
while ($line = $sr.readline()){ 
    if ($line -match "London"){ 
        $line} 
    }
}
```

However can anyone suggest a simple way to limit results so if a 100 matches are found I can choose to output only 1 result to file (or choose the quantity of lines that are output)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something similar to Get-Unique command in Powershell, or get-content with a -first 1 switch.  Is there something similar I can use on the example code posted?  Thank you

Comment: I'm confused - `Get-Unique` and `Get-Content -first 1` would produce entirely different output. Are you looking for all unique lines containing "London", or just _a_ line from the file containing "London"?

Comment: I'm looking ideally for a method restrict the numbers returned eg. the unique value only once.  So if a file contains the string London 100 times it will only output it once to my report.  Can you advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a loop constraint to your `if` statement. For example:

```
$sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader(Get-Item C:\Temp\a.txt)
$limit = 3; $i = 0
while ($line = $sr.ReadLine()) {   
    if ($line -match "London" -and $i -lt $limit) {
            $line
            $i += 1
    }
}
```

would limit the number of lines returned containing "London" to whatever you set the `$limit` variable to (in this case, up to the three first line matches found would be returned).

Comment: Thanks Kohlbrr - that's just what I was looking for

Comment: @Kohlbrr - Perhaps I am reading this incorrectly, but it appears that after 3 matches are found the remaining 874,385,192 lines will be read. What would be a good way to break out of the read loop? Will `while (($i -lt $limit) -and ($line = $sr.ReadLine()))` do it?